# SPARC - Bit mask without shift

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, sparc

I'm learning SPARC assembly and I have to create a script that extracts a field from a register. The script accepts 3 values, initial number, field start position, field length.
It can't use any shift functions, but it can use multiply and divide.
I'm currently suffering from a respiratory virus, and am subsequently on a significant amount of drugs. I'm having a lot of difficulty figuring out where to even start on this.
Some direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply by 2 is a left-shift and divide by 2 is a right shift (at least for unsigned numbers).

If you want to left shift by 2 bits, that's a multiply by 4.

So, for example, if you have the binary value:

```
b15              b0
v                 V
0000 1111 0101 1000
```

and you wanted to extract b3 and b2, you would AND the whole lot with 0xc0 and divide by 4.

```
0000 1111 0101 1000
0000 0000 0000 1100  <- AND with 0xc0
-------------------
0000 0000 0000 1000
-------------------
0000 0000 0000 0010  <- divide by 4
```

Since this sounds suspiciously like homework (and I haven't coded for SPARC for a **long** time), I won't attempt to give you a finished solution - that should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I should have made it more clear; I was only looking for direction not a solution. This should be perfect, I'll see what I can do.